# How to allow a script to be run by anyone anywhere

Tags: shell-script, path

This topic has been discussed already but every post I've read just confuses me even more.

For example, take this simple bash hello world script called test. I created it as the user Bill and did a `chmod 755 test` to make it executable. The script resides in `/home/Bill/scripts` and I tried doing exports `PATH=$PATH:/home/Bill/scripts`

While I'm in that directory I can run the script fine using `./test`. But if I back out into `/home/Bill` I get a "-bash: ./test: No file or directory"

And if I switch into root, I can't find the script even though I've added it to my environment path or I think I did using the export command.

I've also read that I can add the script path into my `/etc/sudoers` and have no password required but this requires the user to run `sudo ./test`. Is there someway to just make this script universally accessible and executable from any user anywhere?

As another side note, i'm kind of confused on the difference between `./test` vs `test` I created the script as `test` but when I or any other user runs it do they run it as `./test` or just `test`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can execute a script either by specifying a path (relative or absolute) to the script, or by ensuring that the directory containing the script is in your shell's search `$PATH`.

Temporarily ignoring the fact that `test` is not a good name for this example, as there are other `test`s your shell may choose to execute, you can always execute the script by name `test` if the containing directory is in your `$PATH`.  This is what you have done with `export PATH=$PATH:/home/Bill/scripts`.  In the terminal in which you have set this `$PATH`, you can execute `test` regardless of your current working directory.

If the script is *not* in your `$PATH`, or you want to explicitly specify *which* `test` you want to execute, you can provide not just the filename, but a relative or absolute path to the file.  So, again regardless of your current working directory, you can always execute the script by providing the full path: `/home/Bill/scripts/test`.

You can also execute the script by providing a relative path; for some examples, where the prompt indicates your working directory:

```
/home/Bill/scripts$ ./test
/home/Bill$ scripts/test
/home/Bill/documents$ ../scripts/test
/home/James/documents$ ../../Bill/scripts/test
```

The reason you receive an error when you tried to execute

```
/home/Bill$ ./test
```

is because there is no file `/home/Bill/test`, which is what you are trying to execute ("the file `test` in the current directory `.`")

---

If you want all users to be able to run the script simply with its name, without giving a absolute or relative path to the script, it must be in everyone's `$PATH`.  You can do this either by having every user add `/home/Bill/scripts` to their `$PATH`, or by putting the script in a location that is in the default `$PATH` for all users, such as `/usr/local/bin`. But you'll have to call your script something other than `test`, because `test` is a special case: it's a shell built-in command.

Answer (score 1):

Naming a script "test" is not a good idea because there is a "test" command already:

```
type test
test is a shell builtin
```

Beside this the PATH variable always work to find a program or script. So place the path of your script to PATH with

```
export PATH=/your/place/to/directory_of_script:$PATH
```

will make your script accessible. But do not use names of shell builtin or otherwise already existing names of programs or scripts!

Comment: please take in mind that user's need also access-rights (use chmod or setfacl) to provide access rights to the script. also you need to think about top level directory access. this is beside the PATH configuration !